# Elm - How to process type Signal Bool

Tags: types, signals, mouse, elm

The following function determines whether or not a given position is inside a shape:

```
isPosInShape: (Int,Int) -> (Float,Float) -> (Float,Float) -> Bool
isPosInShape (posX, posY) (w, h) (shapeX, shapeY) =
  let
    (pX,pY) =
      (toFloat posX, toFloat posY)
  in
    (pX > shapeX - w/2) && (pX < shapeX + w/2) && (pY > shapeY - h/2) && (pY < shapeY + h/2)
```

when fed Mouse positions, this can calculate whether or not the mouse is in a shape region (approximated by a rectangle region):

```
Signal.map3 isPosInShape Mouse.position (width, height) (sX, sY)
```

where `(width, height)` and `(sX, sY)` are of type `Signal.Signal (Float, Float)`.

The issue here is that the returned value of the above expression is of type `Signal Bool` - how can this be fed into conditional functions like `if`?
They would only accept `Bool` types.

Is there a best practice that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use `Signal.map` to process the value held by the signal. Your code snippet is already doing just that with `Signal.map3` (it's called `map3` because it accepts three different signal parameters).

When you use `Signal.map`, your mapping function doesn't need to deal with Signals at all. Case in point: your `inPosInShape` function deals with primitives without respect to Signals.

Therefore, if you want to do something with the signal generated by `isPosInShape`, you'll need to use `Signal.map`, and provide a function that accepts a `Bool` and turns it into something else.

Here's a completely contrived example which acts on the boolean from the `Keyboard.space` signal, which is of type `Signal Bool`:

```elm
import Graphics.Element exposing (show)
import Keyboard

doSomething : Bool -> String
doSomething b =
  if b then
    "The spacebar is pressed!"
  else
    "Please press the spacebar!"

main = Signal.map (show << doSomething) Keyboard.space
```